# Keep unmatching monthly values from two tables in a many to many scenario in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, many-to-many, outer-join

I have two tables 'Solution' and 'Project'. There is a many to many relationship between them. Both tables are tracking 'revenue' at monthly level but there can be certain months where Solution only will have revenue and certain months where Project only will have revenue.

```
Solution
--------
Solution01
Solution02
Solution03
Solution04

Solution - Project Mapping
--------------------------
Solution01   Proj1
Solution01   Proj2
Solution02   Proj1
Solution02   Proj3

Revenue - Solution
-------------------
Solution01   2023-Jan     1000
Solution01   2023-Mar     2000
Solution02   2023-April   4000

Revenue - Project
----------------
Proj1       2023-Jan      250
Proj1       2023-May      110
Proj3       2023-May      150

I want this to be listed as below
---------------------------------

Solution     Project    Month     Solution_Revenue    Project_Revenue
--------     -------    -----     ----------------    ---------------
Solution01   Proj1      2023-Jan    1000               250
Solution01   Proj1      2023-Mar    2000               0
Solution01   Proj2      2023-Jan    1000               0
Solution01   Proj2      2023-Mar    2000               0           
Solution02   Proj1      2023-Jan    0                  250
Solution02   Proj1      2023-May    0                  110
Solution02   Proj1      2023-April  4000               0
Solution02   Proj3      2023-April  4000               0
Solution02   Proj3      2023-May    0                  150
```

keeping the solution-project mapping intact is crucial.

How can i do this in pyspark?

I tried below,

```
df = Solution_Project_Mapping.alias("a").join(Revenue - Solution.alias("b"),\
                                    col("a.Solution_Id") = col("b.Solution_Id"), how = ("left"))

df2 = df.alias("a").join(Revenue-Projcect.alias("b"),\
                (col("a.Project_Id") == col(b.Project_Id") & col("a.month") = col(b.month"))        
                ,how="outer"))
```

But using above I loose the Solution to Project mapping.

i.e. There are some rows as,

Solution     Project    Month     Solution_Revenue    Project_Revenue

---

Null         Proj1      2023-Jan  Null                250